# How to boot dd generated Win95 Image?

Tags: windows, boot, iso-image, qemu

I want to boot an old Win95 Image, that I generated with dd by a real drive.

`qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu pentium3 -m 512 -rtc clock=host,base=localtime -drive file=win95.iso,format=raw`
results in qemu being stuck at "Booting from Hard Disk...". What could be the problem?
I also tried `-hda win95.iso` or `-cdrom win98.iso` with no success. I seems like qemu does not recognize the image.

file win95.iso: `win95.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "MSWIN4.1", sectors/cluster 16, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 240, hidden sectors 63,1 unlabeled`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to boot an old Win95 Image, that I generated with dd by a real
> drive.

As a real image on a new machine (NTFS, new CPU)?  No, that will not work. Windows 95 is simply too old for that.

With a good Virtual App, you can load it as a Virtual Machine.

I have Windows 95 running with VMware Workstation V16.

The virtual app (whatever you might wish to try) must list Windows 95 as a supported guest machine.

It might be possible to use an older version of VMware Converter and do a P2V conversion of the image to a virtual machine. Current version of converter is unlikely to P2V a Windows 95 machine.

Otherwise you would need a Windows 95 CD to make the machine.  (available on eBay).

Comment: I have virtualbox avaible on my machine and I was able to create a VDI file of the dd generated image with "vboxmanage convertdd". Virtualbox offers to create a Win95 VM. So it looks like it is supported. Booting with the VDI file however, does also not work. Virtualbox gets stuck with a blinking cursor (like qemu).

Comment: You would need a  Windows 95 CD to build the Virtual Machine.